# Why are some of these names ending in -a and some in -ae?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

Reading LLPSI, in PENSVM B of Capitula 2, there is this passage:

> Syra ancilla Aemiliae est. Aemilia domina Syrae est.

Are Aemiliae and Syrae the direct objects, thus they are conjugated that way?

Comment: They are both in the genitive case, fem.sing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The the word *ancilla* and the names *Syra* and *Aemilia* are declined (rather than conjugated) according to the first declension, as shown in the following chart from [Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/1st-declension-stem-paradigm-and-gender):

[image]

The different forms of the declensions indicate the function of the nouns in a sentence. They often do the work of what we do with prepositional phrases. Rather than the prepositional phrase *of the star*, the same idea can be expressed in Latin with a single word: *stellae*.

From the chart, you can see that the **-a** ending indicates the **nominative** **singular**. (It could also indicate the **ablative singular**, but that possibility is ruled out by the context.) The **nominative singular** is what's to be expected for the subject and predicate of sentences of [the verb *sum*](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/sum) (or *esse* when indicated by the infinitive):

[image]

From the first chart, you can also see that the **-ae** indicates either the **nominative plural**, or the **genitive** or **dative singular**. The **plural** doesn't make sense because it's only one person, so that leaves either the **genitive** or the **dative singular**. For the given context, the **genitive** makes more sense, because the meaning is *of Syra* or *of Aemillia*.

From that we can conclude that the sentences mean:

> Syra is the servant of Aemilia. Aemilia is the mistress of Syra.

Of course, in English, that can be stated more simply by saying:

> Syra is Aemilia's servant. Aemilia is Syra's mistress.

Sentences of the verb *sum* don't have direct objects (except perhaps in subordinate clauses). Rather, direct object follow transitive verbs. Any noun that serves as a direct object will appear in the **accusative**. Here's an example:

> Caesar librum amavit.

In this sentence  *librum* is the direct object: *Caesar loved the book*. Because of that, *librum* appears in the **accusative singular**. Being of the second declension its ending is **-um**.